# Inner join to select MAX value from the SUM of Rows

Tags: mysql, sum, inner-join, max

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a2df

I am trying to select a column "photo_name" by counting the MAX value of SUM(`valid`)

the preferred results is "test5.jpg" but after hours of trying, I still can't figure it out ,

below is my previous approach, but it doesn't work

```
SELECT photo_name FROM
(
SELECT  a.*
    FROM    test a  
    INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT  *, SUM(valid) v
    FROM    test
    WHERE   page_id = 3 AND `valid` = 1

    ) b ON  MAX(b.v)
)c
```

Please help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work. It sums the `valid` column for each photo, orders high-to-low for the sum, then limits results to the top row:

```
SELECT photo_name, SUM(valid) AS sum_valid
FROM test
GROUP BY photo_name
ORDER BY sum_valid DESC
LIMIT 1
```